# SQL query inside max function

Tags: sql, group-by

I can't take the max value from a SQL query.

I wrote this SQL query:

```
SELECT P.p_name AS leadergame, COUNT(winner) AS wins
FROM game G
INNER JOIN player P ON (P.id = G.winner) 
GROUP BY winner;
```

and I get this result:

```
leadergame     wins
-------------------
Nick            2
Andrew          1
Alex            3
```

How can I take only the leadergame with the most wins?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question relies heavily on the RDBMS that you are using

#### SQL Server

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 P.p_name AS leadergame, COUNT(G.winner) AS wins
FROM game G
INNER JOIN player P ON P.id = G.winner
GROUP BY P.p_name
ORDER BY COUNT(G.winner) DESC;
```

#### MySQL\Postgres

```sql
SELECT P.p_name AS leadergame, Count(winner) AS wins
FROM game G
INNER JOIN player P ON (P.id = G.winner) 
GROUP BY winner
ORDER BY wins DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Or you can apply a SubQuery and achieve the results

```sql
SELECT P.p_name AS leadergame, Count(winner) AS wins
FROM game G
INNER JOIN player P ON (P.id = G.winner) 
GROUP BY winner
HAVING Count(winner) = (
    SELECT MAX(win_count)
    FROM (
        SELECT Count(winner) AS win_count
        FROM game
        GROUP BY winner
    ) AS max_wins
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward. Append `ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1` to your query. Like this.

```sql
SELECT P.p_name AS leadergame, COUNT(winner) AS wins
FROM game G
INNER JOIN player P ON (P.id = G.winner) 
GROUP BY winner
ORDER BY COUNT(winner) DESC
LIMIT 1
```